# How to use the sequelize-mock variable multiple times in the same test case

Tags: node.js, mocking, sequelize.js, mocha.js, sinon

For this project, I am using `MySQL DB` and `Sequelize` ORM. For testing, I am using `mocha`, `chai` and `sinon` modules.

I am having a `User` model and method `createUser`. I am trying to use `sequelize-mock` to mock the users data. Here is the code snippet:

```
const SequelizeMock = require("sequelize-mock");
const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
const userMock = dbMock.define("users");

// Mocking multiple records in a single mock
// Reference - github.com/BlinkUX/sequelize-mock/issues/55#issuecomment-383311654

userMock.$queueResult([
  userMock.build({
    id: 1,
    userName: "Superman"
  }),
  userMock.build({
    id: 2,
    userName: "Batman"
  })
]);

describe("createUser test", () => {
  it("creates user", async () => {
    console.log(`--------------- 1 -----------------`);
    let allUsers = await userMock.findAll();
    console.log(`allUsers = ${JSON.stringify(allUsers)}`);
    expect(allUsers.length).to.equal(2);

    console.log(`--------------- 2 -----------------`);
    allUsers = await userMock.findAll();
    console.log(`allUsers = ${JSON.stringify(allUsers)}`);
    expect(allUsers.length).to.equal(2);
    console.log(`--------------- 3 -----------------`);
  });
});
```

But `userMock.findAll()` works only once. Here is the console log for the same:

```
createUser test
--------------- 1 -----------------
allUsers = [{"id":1,"userName":"Superman","createdAt":"2020-01-01T09:36:48.286Z","updatedAt":"2020-01-01T09:36:48.286Z"},{"id":2,"userName":"Batman","createdAt":"2020-01-01T09:36:48.286Z","updatedAt":"2020-01-01T09:36:48.286Z"}]
--------------- 2 -----------------
allUsers = [{"id":1,"createdAt":"2020-01-01T09:43:35.030Z","updatedAt":"2020-01-01T09:43:35.030Z"}]
```

Here are my questions:

1. Why is the value of allUsers varying when called multiple times?
2. How can I use the same userMock multiple times? This is needed for the following case. In order to test the update functionality, I need use `findOne()` and update the data of one User record (present in userMock). And then I need to find that updated record using findOne() again.

**PS -** Github test repo URL - https://github.com/shrirambalakrishnan/sequelize-mock-test.
You can run `npm test` to run the tests and look at the console log.

Comment: did you figure out a fix on this? I set my autoQueryFallback: false but still findAll() and findOne() give me the same dataset.